# Spring Zuul Oauth2 JWT flow using curl

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

I am using a ZuulProxy with @EnableOauth2Sso and @EnableResourceServer which points to an Auth Server with form based authentication.

This flow works correctly when I use a browser which redirects to the login form in my auth server and then redirects back to Zuul, performs the Oauth dance and then redirects to my intended URL.

I am not able to simulate this flow using a curl command or a non-browser utility to make it work? Is this posible with Oauth JWT tokens with spring scurity?

```
curl --request POST -u clien:cliensecret "http://server:9999/uaa/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=user&password=pass"
```

Returns the access_token, refresh_token but a subsequent call with the Header "Bearer token" does not seem to work.

Comment: Assuming it works in the browser, I don't see why it couldn't also work with curl or similar. Are you sure you aren't just missing a header, or typo'd your auth credentials (I see "clien" as opposed to "client" as your basic auth user, but that's a guess). What kind of error are you getting back when you make that curl? Also, try running with -v to get more verbose curl output.

Comment: The above request is to get the auth token from the auth server which works fine. I just ripped out sensitive info from the request to post it in the question and made a typo there. I do receive the auth token successfully from the auth server. It just does not work when i submit requests with the token as a Bearer token to my resource server. I've read some where that the auth works with cookies. I believe in the browser the session is maintained by the JSESSIONID cookie.

Comment: Yeah I believe that's the case as well. You could always copy as curl from the chrome/ff network tab, which should have all the cookies/headers you need. Sounds like there's just some missing info in the request.

Comment: Yea.. looks like the requests in the browser do not send the Token at all but just the JSESSIONID and copying the command as cURL works too from command line. I assumed the Oauth dance should also work with the Bearer token.